# Any way to group projects in folders in Project Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Using Visual Studio one can create solution-level folders and group projects and other solution items in some custom way, e.g.:

[image]

I've installed RAD Studio XE 10, and I've been surprised to see old "good" (actually, not so good) Project Manager, which almost hasn't changes from BDS 2006. Particularly, I can't find any obvious way to group projects in the project group like VS Solution Explorer allows:

[image]

Could you clarify, is there any way to do, what I want?
Maybe, there are some tricks?

Comment: You can only do that if the physical structure is the same, i.e. if e.g. Unit1.pas is in a different folder. You can not define groups in the project manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to do, what I want? Maybe, there are some tricks?

No, what you want cannot be done. I suggest that you submit a feature request.